# Shopify 400 Error while updating discount code in checkout

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am using shopify python api to update the discount code in checkout. Below are the steps -

```
#Retrieve the checkout using
checkout = shopify.Checkout.find('6ad53674ac258e67cac363921af7d6c2')

#update the discount code,
checkout.discount_code = 'CADAD12'

#Save the checkout
checkout.save()
```

I get the following error while saving the checkout,

Response(code=400, body="{"errors":{"credit_card":"must be a hash"}}")

Please help with this issue.

Also, please let me know if there is any other way to apply the discount code to the checkout using shopify_python_api